# Is there anything I can do on the front end to read the response of a POST request to another domain?

Tags: cross-domain

I have a form

```
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        ...
      </form>
    );
  }
```

On submit I make a post request and print the response

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    axios.post('https://.../oauth2/token', {
      firstName: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password,
      grant_type: password
    })
    .then(response => console.log(response))

    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

The printed response is

> Failed to load https://.../oauth2/token: Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

I understand that this is supposed to protect against cookie abuse. But is there anything I can do on the front end to get the response? Maybe I can state in the request that I don't want to use any cookie rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource*

Right there tells me what's wrong. You've got a problem with CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing). If you're using Chrome, you can use an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) for it.

For a permanent solution, you'll have to enable CORS on your host server. I can't offer much help with that, as I've got no idea what your backend looks like. You can try searching for " CORS". Personally, I just use the extension when I'm developing for simplicity's sake, but I'm only working on an AngularJS mobile app.